# Cannot contact Firebase

Tags: firebase, build.gradle

Build.gradle(Project) modified to add:

•   i

```
id `'com.google.gms.google-services' version "4.4.0" apply false`
```

Build.gradle(App) modified to add:
•

```
id `'com.google.gms.google-services'`
```

en
•

```
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.4.0"))
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:22.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.9.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.3.0'
```

I have adjusted the gradles above in this way, but I still get the error message below. (I use Android Studio Dolphin) How can I solve this?

> 2023-10-31 11:45:25.623 6335-6335/com.example.management W/FirebaseApp: Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project.
> 2023-10-31 11:45:25.623 6335-6335/com.example.management I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful

Comment: Have you tried to remove the versions for the Firebase implementations? Since you are using BOM, there is no need to add them.

Answer (score 0):

try this out

##### Install the required command line tools

1. If you haven't already, install the Firebase CLI.(https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#setup_update_cli)
2. Log into Firebase using your Google account by running the following command:

```
firebase login
```

3. Install the FlutterFire CLI by running the following command from any directory:

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

##### Configure your apps to use Firebase

Use the FlutterFire CLI to configure your Flutter apps to connect to Firebase.
From your Flutter project directory, run the following command to start the app configuration workflow:

```
flutterfire configure
```

if the flutterfire command is not recognize add it to path

##### Initialize Firebase in your app

1. From your Flutter project directory, run the following command to install the core plugin:

```
flutter pub add firebase_core
```

2. From your Flutter project directory, run the following command to ensure that your Flutter app's Firebase configuration is up-to-date:

```
flutterfire configure
```

3. In your `lib/main.dart` file, import the Firebase core plugin and the configuration file you generated earlier:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
```

4.Also in your lib/main.dart file, initialize Firebase:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

5. Rebuild your Flutter application

for more details check out this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android